# Parsing large files NOT in binary (Python or C++)

Tags: python, c++, parsing, ascii, bigdata

As a disclaimer, I'm hardly a computer scientist, but I've been reading everything I can on the subject of efficient file i/o to try and tackle this facet of a project I'm working on.

I have a very large (10 - 100 GB) log file of comma-separated values that I need to parse through. The first value labels it as "A" or "B"; for every "A" line, I need to examine the line before it and the line after it, and if either line before or after it meets a criterion, I want to store it in memory or write it to a file. The lines are not uniform in size.

That is my specific problem: I can't seem to locate an **efficient** way to do this in a non-binary file. With a binary file, I'd simply iterate over the file once and rewind to and fro with a logical check. I've investigated memory mapping, but it seems structured for binary files; my current code is Pythonic and takes weeks to run [see disclaimer].

My other question would be-- how easily could parallelism be invoked to help here? I have a notion of how -- map the file out three lines at a time and send each chunk to each node [lines 1,2,3 go to one node; lines 3,4,5 go to another ...], but I have no idea how to go about implementing this.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: In Python you have [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) to process the file.

Comment: Do you need it to be 'invented here', or is using `grep` an option?

Answer (score 2):

Just read the lines in a loop. Keep track of the previous line in memory and examine it when needed.

Pseudocode:

```
for each line:
    previousLine := currentLine
    read currentLine from file
    do processing...
```

This is efficient assuming you're already reading every line into memory anyway, and if you use a proper buffering scheme for reading the file (read large chunks at a time into memory).

I don't think parallelism will help in this situation. If properly written, the bottleneck of the program should be disk I/O, and multiple threads/processes can't read from disk any faster than a single thread. Parallelism only improves CPU-bound problems.

For what it's worth you can "seek" in ASCII files the same way you can with binary files. You would just keep track of the file offset each time you begin to read a line, and store that offset so you know where to seek back to later. Depending on how this is implemented this will never perform better than the above, though, and sometimes worse (you would want the file data to be buffered in memory so that the "seeking" is a memory operation and not a disk operation; you definitely want to read the file contents sequentially to maximize cache-ahead benefits).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a first pass. Assumes properly formatted lines of text.

```
from itertools import chain

with open('your-file') as f:
    prev_line = None
    cur_line = f.readline()
    for next_line in chain(f, [None]):
        pieces = cur_line.split(',')
        if pieces[0] == 'A':
            check_against_criterion_if_not_none(prev_line)
            check_against_criterion_if_not_none(next_line)
        prev_line, cur_line = cur_line, next_line
```

A nifty trick is tacking on that extra 'None' at the end of the file, using itertools.chain, so that code properly checks the last line of the file against the 2nd to last line.